# sql server dateadd() using column name year and not keyword 'year'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view, dateadd

I am using DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE()) to pull the last thee years worth of data on a rolling period.

I also have a column called Year, the view I am creating is using the MyTable.Year and not the sql keyword 'year'.

e.g DATEADD(MyTable.year, -3, GETDATE())

It resolves it every time in the view which is really annoying.  I'm a bit rusty, been out of this for about 4 years.

How do I make sure it uses the keyword 'year', I find it strange it is doing this.  Any explanation on this would also be helpful.  SQL Server 2016

Thanks guys.

[image]

[image]
EDIT: I have edited my misplaced schema notation and identified the table name, sorry for confusion

Comment: what other values can be in that column of the year table ?

Comment: it is only a string value representing the year '2019' and so on.  The table is a list of timesheets.  Year is a field in said table

Comment: can you show us the query you have now, and the structure for this table year ?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually after here. The first parameter of `DATEADD` can't be a column name, it needs to be one of the time periods defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments). Sample Data and Expected result will be really useful.

Comment: Yes I understand.  I know I need to use WHERE table.dbo.Date > DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE())

Comment: so you want something like `DATEADD('2019', -3, GetDate())`? That wont work, you need to pass a datepart like year, or month, or day or...

Comment: `table.dbo.Date` makes no sense. `dbo` is a schema, so it goes *before* the name of the table. Using the Schema name when referencing a column in a query is dereprecated though. Unless `Date` is the name of a `table`, which implies you have a database called `table`???

Comment: The table called Timesheets, has a field called Year.  The view automatically changes the sql keyword 'year', used in the DATE ADD function, to be the Timesheets.year field, I am trying to force the keyword in the function but the view is being stupid.  Is this a bug or a config issue

Comment: why dont you show us the view and the table structure, maybe then we better understand what you mean

Comment: *"but the view is being stupid"* I don't think it is, to be honest. What you're saying doesn't make sense. Yousay you want to do `DATEADD(table.dbo.year, -3, GETDATE()))` but that looks like you're trying to use the table `Date` in the database `table` as the 1st argument for `DATEADD`. Using a table for replacement of a defined time period value makes no sense. The values for the first arguement are clearly defined, and you certainly can't pass a table object for it.

Comment: I understand how the function works, I didn;t help with my schema placement.  I know I need to use the keyword 'year', my query is 'WHERE Timesheets.Date > DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE())' but when I add the 'year' keyword in the DATEADD function while creating the view, it seems to immediately resolve it to use the timesheets.year field inside the function, which is not allowed I understand

Comment: why dont you show us the view and the table structure, maybe then we better understand what you mean

Comment: This is definitely nothing to do with query engine, or how the query compiles - [Demo on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91bf0644a76cb0384f258ed72a5eef67). What you are describing sounds like something that is happening with intellisense in your IDE. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: if your editor has problems with the keyword `year` then try `select dateadd(yy, -3, getdate())` in stead of `select dateadd(year, -3, getdate())`

Comment: Thanks, yes you get what I mean, I didn't help anyone with my poor explanation.  I am looking for a way around 'year' but using yy fixed it.  Thank you.  I am using SSMS 2016, I thought maybe IDE issue I wanted to get round it.

Comment: using 'yy' in place of 'year' fixed the issue for me.  Must be an IDE issue on my end, so annoying

Comment: ok glad we got this sorted out. Next time you ask a question give as much information as possible that will help getting answers more easy

Comment: you can always answer your own question, explain why you got this and what fixed it. This might help future users of SO with the same problem

Comment: @Guido, you answered it first.  Please add it and you get the kudos

Comment: OK I just did post an answer

Comment: Rather than images, include the code. Those images are far too small for me to be able to read the SQL.

Comment: They're clear at my end, they were reduced in resolution when I embedded the images - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your editor has problems with the keyword `YEAR` and replaces it with a value from a column that is also called `year`

This can be solved by using a synonym for the keyword year in the DateAdd function.
So instead of

```
dateadd(year, -3, getdate())
```

use

```
dateadd(yy, -3, getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but you want to enforce the keyword, so you want to subtract 3 years from the current date, correct? This should work:

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy, -3, GETDATE())
```

or

```
SELECT DATEADD(yyyy, -3, GETDATE())
```

(unless you have columns named yy and yyyy ;-))

Otherwise forgive my misunderstanding...

Comment: This was the fix, thank you.  Any idea why this would be behaving in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You could put your table in a subquery and alias [Year] column.
Something like

```
SELECT ... FROM (SELECT [Year] AS "MyYear" FROM ...) X
```

(or use CTE)

Then Year would only mean the keyword.